# Javascript doesn't seem to be running when loading React native through Action extension on ios

Tags: objective-c, react-native

This is from my View Controller that is launched by the Action extension:

```
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];


  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
      jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  BOOL found = NO;

  // Find the item containing the results from the JavaScript preprocessing.
  for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
      if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList options:nil completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
          [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            NSDictionary *initialProps = @{@"isActionExtension": @YES,  @"preprocessingResults": dictionary[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey]};

            RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                                moduleName:@"QCheckoutRN"
                                                         initialProperties:initialProps
                                                             launchOptions:nil];

            rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];


            NSLog(@"High Score Button Pressed");
            UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            vc.view = rootView;
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


          }];
        }];
        found = YES;
      }
      break;
    }
    if (found) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    // We did not find anything
    [self doneWithResults:nil];
  }
```

It loads the view generated with RN and I see buttons from the jsx file but no lifecycle methods are being fired, cant do alert() and buttons don't trigger actions.

Not sure how to debug this as it seems that the JS Runtime if dead, which is strange as it did the initial render. Am I loading it wrong? 
It looks similar to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps but they are using an action to call the view while im loading it right away. Im a noob at iOS development and Objective-c so if someone can point out the issue it would help a lot to get it running.

Comment: Biggest clue is : "Tried to display alert view but there is no application window" when trying to use AlertIOS

Comment: So I got to a conclusion that JSC instance is running but for some reason nothing related to the view is working.